# How many inrush current limiting thermistor do I need and where should I place them?

Tags: thermistor, bridge-rectifier, inrush-current

In most designs they place a single NTC thermistor in series before the bridge rectifier and in some two or four:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRepQN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Isn't a single thermistor sufficient for limiting the inrush current? when and why do we need four thermisotrs?

Comment: One is sufficient.

Comment: @VillageTech For example in [this tutorial](https://www.ametherm.com/blog/inrush-current/capacitor-inrush-current) the author used four, why?

Comment: The left two - are de facto in serial. It doesn't make sense. Right two - the same. And splitting to left and right - hmm, maybe as additional protection in case of bridge short circut... But in normal conditions four are as good as one. Maybe the autor loves symmetry? Who nows? Artist? Or somethink like that... From an electrical point of view it doesn't make sense - all are connected in serial. EDIT: the circuit, shown in mentioned tutorial, has switch 120V/240V - it makes big difference. But in typical application (w/out switch) one is enough.

Comment: Isolation transformer should remove the need for 2 even if you are US vs EU power 120 / 240. I see no reason he has sets of 2. Unless for his massive load of 10mF, a single 1 is not enough, although I feel that is a poor example to use for people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTC thermister in the AC side of the Bridge rectifier is best .The big filter cap on the DC side gives some             protection  for the Bridge from voltage spikes.There is these days motivation to bypass the NTC when the system is up and running in order to save power .A relay is robust and simple and the coil wastes less power than the hot NTC .When the NTC is bypassed by the relay on the AC side the relay is switching AC where it will live up to its ratings .One NTC in the AC side is adequate .Using two NTCs one in each leg can be cost effective at high power and gives a more symmectrical circuit layout which can help EMC .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the author wanted to indicate the alternative mounting position of the NTC in the design, he did not meant four NTC at the same time otherwise it makes no sense.